# How to get the path of a drag & dropped file in Maya's MEL

Tags: maya, mel

Drag & drop a Maya MEL file into Maya and the contents of the MEL file will be executed.
Is there a way to get the absolute path of the file when dragging and dropping?

Comment: Does it have to be `MEL`, or would you be able to use `Python`? From what I can tell, you would need to leverage the `whatIs` function in MEL, which is a bit cumbersome, but very possible.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It must be MEL.
I want to load it into the scene by dragging and dropping. Python cannot be dragged and dropped.
How can I use the `whatIs` command? I tried `whatIs "test.mel";` but it was printed as `Unknown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can get you started

**test.mel**:

```
global proc FindMe() {}

print("whatIs result -> " + `whatIs "FindMe"`);
```

Drag-dropping the file into Maya produces the following output:

```
> source "C:/Users/itypewithmyhands/Desktop/test.mel";
> whatIs result -> Mel procedure found in: C:/Users/itypewithmyhands/Desktop/test.mel
```

Interesting points to note:

1. Drag-drop seems to simply produce a `source <file>` statement, which means you'll have to do some internal magic unknown to me in order to know if the file was actually dropped, or simply sourced
2. The `proc` you search for has to be marked **global**

You need to regex (or similar) the result of the `whatIs` command to get the path you're after. Something like `.*found in: (.+?\.mel)` seems to work well enough. [Example](https://regexr.com/5pqvm)